# Data sharing in multiple spark applications

Tags: hadoop, caching, apache-spark

Thanks in advance.

I need to work on Spark application(s), where one Spark job will create or prepare data and that data will be shared across multiple spark jobs running in parallel.

I tried to find out the solution for this and I came across Apache Ignite, however, the requirement is to use In-Memory HDFS (cache HDFS) instead of Ignite.

I tried to get details about DistributedCache as well as Centralized Cache Management in Hadoop. The DistributedCache is now deprecated and mostly used with MapReduce jobs by using job.addCacheFile() or something like that.
Centralized Cache Management require additional configuration in hdfs-size.xml.

How I can use the In-Memory cache for HDFS with Spark or does Spark provides any APIs, where one Spark job can place the file in distributed cache of HDFS and other Spark jobs can use it.

Your answers will be really helpful for me.

Thanks,

Avinash Deshmukh

Comment: It seems that it's normal HDFS with some switches. Probably will work out of the box :)

Comment: Do you know about Spark Job Server? https://github.com/spark-jobserver/spark-jobserver

Comment: Hi Thiago, thanks. Currently I have not gone through this. Will check out and try to check whether it solves the problem. Also, I forgot to mention one point here is we will be using AWS EMR cluster to deploy the Spark applications.